# How to use INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE or INSERT IGNORE with output clause SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to use, INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, or INSERT IGNORE.... in below query.
I have two identical rows and want to insert only one entry in table "configdetails" from result set which i get , I don't want to use unique constraint as it throw error for multiple insertion (e.g for 3 entries, 2 same one unique, I want to insert only 2 unique entry ) , is there any way to do this.

```
 INSERT INTO configdetails(serverid,servertype,configpath,configtype)
                        OUTPUT inserted.configid,'configdetails',cm.Key INTO @Output(ID,TableName,cmKey )
                    SELECT t.ID,cm.servertype,cm.configpath,cm.configtype 
                    FROM configpthmaster cm 
                      CROSS APPLY (SELECT ID FROM @Output WHERE TableName='server_detials')t
                    WHERE cm.appid = @appid
```

Comment: You need to add a unique constraint in order for the `on duplicate` statement to function.

Comment: dont want to use it as it throw error for multiple insertion (e.g for 3 entries, 2 same one unique, I want to insert only 2 unique entry ) @Phylogenesis

Comment: You can't.  Your question is tagged SQL Server, and it doesn't support `on duplicate key update`.

Comment: How about Select Distinct t.ID, cm.servertype... and after the Cross Apply, Select Top 1 ID From...